# What is the origin of the overall phase of a state ket?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, complex-numbers

In, Sakurai's textbook on quantum mechanics, he mentions the "Overall phase" of a state ket while discussing the spin half system. What is the origin of this phase term? Is it because the state kets are in a complex space? and the phase term introduced is actually the phase angle between the two vectors? I apologize in advance if the question is naive or I haven't provided enough information.Also, why is the phase term taken into consideration when the superposition of the two spin states are considered( as shown in the image below)?

[image]

Comment: Does [this](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/5126/15820) help? The idea is that $|\psi\rangle$ and $e^{i\phi}|\psi\rangle$ can never be distinguished physically (they correspond to the same ray in the projective Hilbert space)

Comment: Yes. Thank you! It does help.